Is there any way to specify a minimum version in a Swift Package just for one platform without overriding the compatibility with other platforms?
I am working on a Swift Package and I want to add a NLLanguageRecognizer instance, which is only available in macOS 10.14+. At this point the other default minimums for Swift Packages are fine; Xcode is only complaining about macOS. If I specify compatibility with macOS 10.14 however, that would remove compatibility with other platforms unless I also specify all of them.
  platforms: [
    .iOS(.v16),
    .macOS(.v10_14),
    .tvOS(.v16),
    // etc
  ],

(the versions shown above are mostly arbitrary)
So if I need to override the minimum version for macOS is there any way to specify that other than macOS it should just use the defaults for any other platform?
It's not a problem per se that I have to list them, I'd just rather not have to if it's not necessary as there are a bunch of them and I don't care about most of them currently.
In the docs it looks like the default value for platforms is nil, which must be treated internally as using the default minimum platform versions.
